# Insert values in related models based on foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to insert values for related one to many models through a form. I'm having some difficulties.

I have three related models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    member_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='test first name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='test last name')

class Loans (models.Model):
    loan_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    member = models.ForeignKey('Member',related_name='loans')

class Transactions (models.Model):
    transaction_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
    loans = models.ForeignKey('Loans', related_name='transactions')
```

Basically, one Member can have one to many Loans, one Loan can have one to many Transactions (although it should be 0 to many, but I'm just testing at the moment).

I have a form that asks for member's full name, loan id and amount.

Basically I'm trying to find the Member based on the full name, then get the loan based on the id provided, and then create a new transaction for that loan.

What I have done in my view:

```
fullName = request.GET.get('full_name')
loanID = request.GET.get('loan_id')
amount = request.GET.get('amount')
#to get first name
firstName = fullName.partition(' ')[0]
#to get last name
lastName = fullName.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
#to get the member
member = Member.objects.filter(first_name=firstName, last_name = lastName)
#get member's loan based on loanID
l = Loans(loan_id = loanID)
t = Transactions.objects.create(amount = amount, transactions = l)
t.save()
```

I get an error when I submit the form:

> 'transactions' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Am I using the correct approach but not understanding model relationships? 
Or am I totally in the wrong track?

Any help/direction would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that `Loans(loan_id=loanID)` doesn't get the loan from the db, it instantiates a new one with that ID. In this case that doesn't matter, but to actually query it you need to do `Loans.objetcs.get(loan_id=loanID)`. Also note that it's usual to use singular names for model classes: Loan, Transaction, etc.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ahhh you're right, and I just realized I should also get the loan from the member, so Loans.objects.get(loan_id=loanID, member = member). I will test it now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `t = Transactions.objects.create(amount = amount, loans = l)`

There's no `transactions` field in `Transactions`. There are `amount` and `loans` and `loans` is the `Loans` instance you got in `l`

Comment: I will try that, I think I'm confused about "related_name='transactions'", in some queries you use the related_name. I will recheck that also. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

It can also work as follows:

```
l = Loans.objects.get(loan_id = loanID)
t = Transactions.objects.create(loans = l,amount = amount, ,transaction_id=uuid.uuid4())
t.save()
```

And you can get transaction_id also as a primary key , which further you can use as foreign key for another table.